# Signing Java Applet - "Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect"

Tags: java, code-signing, keytool, jarsigner

I have a `.cer` file from a certificate authority (internal). I've imported it into a keystore using the following command:

`keytool -import -alias javaapplet -file certificate.cer -keystore javasign`

I entered a keystore password twice and the keystore was generated in the current directory (which happens to be the same folder the `.jar` is located in.

When trying to sign the file (using `jarsigner appletname.jar javaapplet -keystore javasign`), I get the following error after being prompted for the password:

`Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect`

I *know* the password is correct. When entering the password for the command `keytool -list -v -keystore javasign`, it *does* work. The only time it doesn't work is with the `jarsigner` command.

Any clues as to how to fix this issue and sign my applet?